# Adding a paragraph after a named range in a Google Document also adds it to that range

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I need to create multiple ranges in a doc. In each range there is a paragraph but every time I create a new paragraph in a new range this paragraph is also found in the above range

```
function onOpen(e){
  DocumentApp.getUi()
    .createAddonMenu()
    .addItem('Star', 'yoyo')
    .addToUi();
}

function onInstall(e) {
  onOpen(e);
}

function onInstall(e) {
  onOpen(e);
}
function ver(){
  var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  var ranges=doc.getNamedRanges();
  Logger.log('%s ',ranges.length);
  for(var index=0 ; index<ranges.length; index++){
    for(var t=0; t<ranges[index].getRange().getRangeElements().length;t++){
     Logger.log('%s y es de %s',ranges[index].getName(), index);
    }
  }
}

function yoyo(){
  var doc=DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  var body=doc.getBody();
  var rangeBuilde = doc.newRange();
  var name = body.appendParagraph('yasmany');
  var apellido = body.appendParagraph('gonzalez');
  var madre = body.appendParagraph('matilde');
  rangeBuilde.addElement(name);
  rangeBuilde.addElement(apellido);
  rangeBuilde.addElement(madre);
  var re = rangeBuilde.build();
  doc.addNamedRange('ymy2', re);
  ver();
}
```

the `Logger.log()` contains (after  running yoyo 2 times)

```
[16-03-10 16:01:49:888 PST] 2.0 
[16-03-10 16:01:49:892 PST] ymy2 y es de 0.0
[16-03-10 16:01:49:895 PST] ymy2 y es de 0.0
[16-03-10 16:01:49:898 PST] ymy2 y es de 0.0
[16-03-10 16:01:49:901 PST] ymy2 y es de 0.0
[16-03-10 16:01:49:904 PST] ymy2 y es de 0.0
[16-03-10 16:01:49:907 PST] ymy2 y es de 0.0
[16-03-10 16:01:49:913 PST] ymy2 y es de 1.0
[16-03-10 16:01:49:915 PST] ymy2 y es de 1.0
[16-03-10 16:01:49:917 PST] ymy2 y es de 1.0
```

but I want this

```
[16-03-10 16:01:49:888 PST] 2.0 
[16-03-10 16:01:49:892 PST] ymy2 y es de 0.0
[16-03-10 16:01:49:895 PST] ymy2 y es de 0.0
[16-03-10 16:01:49:898 PST] ymy2 y es de 0.0
[16-03-10 16:01:49:913 PST] ymy2 y es de 1.0
[16-03-10 16:01:49:915 PST] ymy2 y es de 1.0
[16-03-10 16:01:49:917 PST] ymy2 y es de 1.0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an Apps Script bug: a paragraph added immediately after a named range gets included in the range, although [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/named-range) clearly says that a named range should be immutable.

To work around this problem, always keep an empty paragraph at the end of the document. The following function is a substitute for `appendParagraph` method which ensures there's always a blank paragraph at the end:

```
function appendPara(body, text) {
  var newPara = body.appendParagraph(text);
  body.appendParagraph('');
  var previous = newPara.getPreviousSibling();
  if (previous.asText().getText().length === 0) {
    previous.removeFromParent();
  }
  return newPara;
}
```

Using this function instead of `appendParagraph` solves the problem:

```
function yoyo() {
  var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  var body = doc.getBody();
  var rangeBuilde = doc.newRange();
  var name = appendPara(body, 'yasmany');
  var apellido = appendPara(body, 'gonzalez');
  var madre = appendPara(body, 'matilde');
  rangeBuilde.addElement(name);
  rangeBuilde.addElement(apellido);
  rangeBuilde.addElement(madre);
  var re = rangeBuilde.build();
  doc.addNamedRange('ymy2', re);
  ver();
}
```

The output after two runs of yoyo is

```
[16-03-11 19:42:47:730 PST] 2.0 
[16-03-11 19:42:47:733 PST] ymy2 y es de 0.0
[16-03-11 19:42:47:734 PST] ymy2 y es de 0.0
[16-03-11 19:42:47:736 PST] ymy2 y es de 0.0
[16-03-11 19:42:47:739 PST] ymy2 y es de 1.0
[16-03-11 19:42:47:740 PST] ymy2 y es de 1.0
[16-03-11 19:42:47:742 PST] ymy2 y es de 1.0
```